# PHP to Codeigniter syntax - Subtraction selecting from db / form input

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to turn a php mysql statement into Codeigniter syntax. The code selects all from a db but the zone difference equals to two form inputs subtracted from each other. Any help is much appreciated.

PHP Version

```
select * from zone_cost where zone_diff =
@(
(select zone from station_zone where station ='FORMINPUT') - (select zone from station_zone where station ='FORMINPUT')
);
```

Codeigniter Attempted Version

```
$zd = (
$this->db->select('zone');
$this->db->get_where('station_zone','station' => $this->form->input('station'));
) - ($this->db->select('zone');
$this->db->get_where('station_zone','station' => $this->form->input('station2'));
);

$this->db->select('zone_cost');
$this->db->where('zone_diff', $zd);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do the substraction with mysql:

```
SELECT
station_zone.zone-sz2.zone as ZoneDiff
FROM station_zone
JOIN station_zone AS sz2 ON (sz2.station="station2")
WHERE station_zone.station="station1"
```

It isn't tested but I think you can use similar query. And after this you can combine your main query so you'll need only ONE query to "answer" your complete data-question.

Comment: do you set station 1 as $this->input->post(station) before hand? I'm not quite sure I understand

Comment: This is only a "pseudo-code", "station1" and "station2" is from your form (`$this->input->get("...")` or `$this->form->input(...)`)

Comment: take a look at how far ive got: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839626/mysql-syntax-error-codeigniter-function-to-calculate-cost

Comment: @Jon I think first you'll need to create a proper query - maybe you can try your attempts in phpmyadmin or in adminer.

Comment: Mile End and Westminster should be strings. When I want create complicated SQL-queries, first I try an example in an SQL-frontend (I'm using adminer). When it works will try to code PHP/CodeIgniter.

Comment: Ok the only issue i have are the '' round the city names. I can manually add them into mysql in phpmyadmin and your beautiful code works fine... but i cant add two '' round .$station1. ?? all of the query is already in "...

Comment: Is this your another question linked above?

Comment: Ooops, I think I understand you. Do you want type a raw query? You can use CI's ActiveRecord to process my "beautiful code" :)
`$this->db->select(...)->from(...)->join(...)->where(...)`

Comment: ive made this so confusing by posting two q's about it... ive got the other question working on one station, i would like to use the join to subtract $station2 - $station1... could you help? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6663/discussion-between-uzsolt-and-jon)

Answer (score 0):

you can check clean syntax of CodeIgniter as bellow.

```
$this->db->select('(column2 - column1) AS `remains_value`')->get_where('tablename1', array('pk' => $pk_val))->row_array();
```

I don't know whether this question is open or not. but the way I come to this question for subtraction of two column inside query only, it might help to future referer.

Thank you