# MYSQL Syntax error - Codeigniter function to calculate cost

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, codeigniter

```
function stationcost($station1,$station2)
{

    $data = array();


    $this->db->select('Zone')->from('station_zone')->where('Station', $station1);
    $Q = $this->db->get();

    $this->db->select('cost')->from('zone_cost')->where('zone', $Q);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {
    $data = $row->Cost;
    return $data;
    }
} 
}
```

If i change $Q to an integer, the function works correctly. I'm yet to add another station to minus the difference to calculate the zone difference

Convert names to zones
$station2 - $station1 = 'calculatedfigure'

Then select cost from zone_cost where zone = 'calculcated figure';

My error message:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 3

SELECT `cost` FROM (`zone_cost`) WHERE `zone` =

Filename: models/station_model.php

Line Number: 59
```

I've tried this

```
$this->db->select('Zone')->from('station_zone')->where('Station', $station2);
    $S2 = $this->db->get();

     $this->db->select('Zone')->from('station_zone')->where('Station', $station1);
    $S1 = $this->db->get();

    $Q = $S2 - $S1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the variable `$Q` does not contain a valid value, presumably because the value passed in `$station1` does not exist in the database. I would have thought that CI would counter this by at least using an empty quoted string, but apparently not.

You need to validate that `$Q` holds a sensible value before you pass it to `where()`. For example, another `num_rows()` check will tell you whether the first query found anything.

Also, you need to pass the field data from `$Q`, not just the object. So in your case, `$Q->row()->Zone`.

Comment: Right, but of course before accessing the `Zone` property of `$Q`, you'll first need to access the row. So in this case, the right way of accessing it is `$Q->row()->Zone`.

Comment: ok got it with one station how do i minus the input of $station2 - $station 1 to get $Q ?? i've posted my attempt in the post

Answer (score 0):

`$Q` is an object which has some fields, at this case only one field: `Zone`. Please check [CodeIgniter Query results](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html)